# order of initialization of static types

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to initialize a static member of a class with another class's static member. But I guess because of some 'undefined' reasons, when the initialization happening, initializer was not yet instantiated. So that the data was not copying because of order of instantiation.

Here it is how it looks like,

```
/* class1.h */
#include "class2.h"

class class1 {
public:
    static const int x;
    static int init()
    {
        return class2::y;
    }
}; 

/* class1.cpp */
const int class::x = class1::init();

/* class2.h */
struct class2 {
    static const int y;
};

/* class2.cpp */
const int class2::y = 5;
```

It was a rough definition of my purpose. As you can see, I am trying to initialize a static data member of class1 with a function call which returns another class's static data member. As I expect that, instead of class1's data member initialized with the function call, it just 'value-initialized'.

As I guess it is happening because of there is no any specification for the order of static type variable execution.

Is there a way to over it?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to read about [“static initialization order fiasco”](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: static variables in different units (which aren't defined inside a function) may be initialized in any order, so you have to design your code to not rely on such an order.  (Some compilers offer pragmas to control the order but that is really opening a can of spaghetti)

Comment: You can't initialize a `static` variable with another `static` variable that reside in different translations units.

Comment: just read the isocpp FAQ's, it was perfect document! thanks for sharing it, but unfortunately could not helped me. I do actually trying to do that with templates (and I am so much new comer to C++) thats why it just overwhelmed me :S. I guess there is no way to do it with templates. I did not mention it on the question because I thought there is a way to do it idiomatically, so I would be able to analogue it. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Besides the question whether this is good design; The answer to your question is rather simple: your definition

```
const int class2::y = 5;
```

should occur **before**

```
const int class::x = class1::init();
```

so one way to get it working, is to keep your headers, but put **both these lines** in your file *class1.cpp*:

```
/* class1.cpp */
const int class2::y = 5;
const int class1::x = class1::init();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but becuase I was trying to do that with templates, your solution could not helped me. I know I did not mention that I am trying to do that with templates but I just though that I would be able to analogue it to templates:S Thank you anyway, atleast I keep that solution for future. Cheers. Sina